# Automatic Property Expansion Using Gradle with escape characters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I'm using property expansion in Gradle. All works fine but for file-paths.

I am using the processResources task in Gradle

```
    processResources {
        filesMatching ('**/application.properties') {
            expand project.properties
        }
    }
```

I have a property in my Spring `application.properties` as follows:

```
root.location = ${rootDir}
```

In my `build.gradle` I have defined the following:

```
ext['rootDir'] = rootProject.buildDir.path + File.separator + "tmp"
```

Result I get in `application.properties` is

```
root.location = D:\Projects\myproject\build\tmp
```

Which turns into D:Projectsmyprojectbuild\tmp in my Spring class when doing:

```
@Value("${cpm.repository.root.location}") String rootLocation;
```

I need the property to be expanded to:

```
root.location = D:\\projects\\myproject\\build\\tmp
```

Because that would result in D:\projects\myproject\build\tmp

What am I doing wrong? Expansion does work as intended, it's just that the '\' in the path are not escapped when expanded.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use `processResources` task to modify your resources.

We are using it that way (with `application.yml` and Gradle Kotlin DSL):

```kotlin
tasks {
    named<ProcessResources>("processResources") {
        outputs.upToDateWhen { false }

        filesMatching("**/application.yml") {
            filter {
                it.replace("#project.version#", version as String)
            }
            filter {
                it.replace("#spring.profiles.active#", profiles)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And of course `#spring.profiles.active#` is a string you want to replace in your file.

Comment: Works like a charm! Used with Spring Boot 3.1.5, thanks!